# Japanese not uploading from Excel to SQL Server using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel, oledb

I have a web page that imports translations from a spreadsheet using `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`;
The process works almost flawlessly, except that Japanese (and likely Korean and Chinese) can not be imported with this method.

```
' Connect to the Excel Spreadsheet
Dim xConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/transText/importUpload/{0}", fileName)) & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

' create your excel connection object using the connection string
 Dim objXConn As New OleDbConnection(xConnStr)
 objXConn.Open()
```

This works for French, Italian, Chinese (on an English PC), Turkish, Spanish, Portuguese, Dutch, Ukrainian, etc. I believe this issue is the `Japanese Windows 7 OS`.

How can I get around this barrier?

After adding the following to the connection string...

```
"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;CharacterSet=UTF-16;"""
```

I double quoted the properties so that the provider could identify each. This cleared the previous error but still will not properly read the file.

If I send the file to an English OS PC, and don't even open the file in Excel on the English OS PC, I can still import the exact same .xls on the English PC but not on the Japanese OS PC. I have tried a few different character sets also.

Comment: Consider adding to your `Extended Properties`, `CharacterSet=UNICODE` like: `"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;CharacterSet=UNICODE"` I would provide this as an answer, but the fact that you are getting Chinese through suggests that it is something else. But... worth a shot.

Comment: Interesting thing is that I can Japanese through as well as long as the PC OS is English.

Comment: Generally English PC windows is UTF16 (I get confused about character sets, so I might be wrong here). It could very well be that Japanese Windows defaults to UTF8. In which case, instead of CharacterSet=Unicode, you may want to try CharacterSet=1200 to force it to use UTF16 through your OLEDB connection. List of codes can be found here: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yea, I have been around the block on this one a few times. There are some additional settings in Excel and the Japanese OS to force Unicode, but they do not seem to be working. Why I am looking back at the connection string. I'll look into your link, thanks.

Comment: Now I am getting this error though...Could not find installable ISAM